# Jump back to navigation controller from tabbar controller - swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a navigation controller with two view controller, the first vc is login and second vc contains some information with tableView. From second vc it will navigate to tabbar controller(all the view controller in the tab bar is embedded into Navigation controller). Now When I click on the first tab it should go back to the second vc. I tried with dismissing, but it's not working as expected. Please shed some light.

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
print("the selected index is : \(tabBar.items?.index(of: item))")
if tabBar.items?.index(of: item) == 0{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add navigation controller for each tab bar item

Comment: It's already added as I mentioned in the question (all the view controller in the tab bar is embedded into Navigation controller)

Comment: How do you show the tabBarController from the second view controller?

Comment: are you opening tabbar controller from your initial navigation controller (not from second view controller) and how (using `present` or `push`)?

Comment: @lobstah  Am presenting tabbar controller from second view controller(second vc is embedded in navigation controller)

Comment: so, in your case, you should present it in your initial navigation controller, or even better create `root` view controller which will present your initial navigation controller and replace it with tabbar controller when needed, then, when user press first tab, dismiss tabbar and show navigation controller in root controller again

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve your issue, but I would say that all of them are not state of the art, because each Tab in a TabbarController should have its own NavigationController. :)

Maybe this way works for you:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("the selected index is : \(tabBar.items?.index(of: item))")
    if tabBar.items?.index(of: item) == 0 {
        let vc = YourSecondViewController() //or get it from your Storyboard
        self.navigationController.setViewControllers([vc], animated: true)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Or if you pushed your controller you could try this one

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("the selected index is : \(tabBar.items?.index(of: item))")
    if tabBar.items?.index(of: item) == 0 {
        self.navigationcontroller.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's going back to the second vc. To be more precise, my 5th tab is logout, so when I clik that tab it should go to the login controller which is the intial controller.